# XSLT select all elements except 3 and put them in a new field

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a tricky question.
Let's assume the following XML :

```
   <a>
     <b>.....some fields and attributes</b>
     <c>.....some fields and attributes</c>
     <d>.....some fields and attributes</d>
     <e>.....some fields and attributes</e>
     <f>.....some fields and attributes</f>
     <g>.....some fields and attributes</g>
     <h>.....some fields and attributes</h>
     <i>.....some fields and attributes</i>
     <j>.....some fields and attributes</j>
   </a>
```

I want to transform it to another xml document with xslt

```
   <a>
     <b>.....some fields and attributes</b>
     <c>.....some fields and attributes</c>
     <d>.....some fields and attributes</d>
     <e>.....some fields and attributes</e>
     <f>.....some fields and attributes</f>
     <g>.....some fields and attributes</g>
     <A new group>
         <h>.....some fields and attributes</h>
         <i>.....some fields and attributes</i>
         <j>.....some fields and attributes</j>
     </A new group>
   </a>
```

The best idea is copying and exclude some elements from copy.

So I started with this part

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then I should exclude the tag , so I use a template to catch those elements and copy their content.

```
<xsl:template match="h | i | j">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but the tricky part is where to put my new tag 
If I put it directly in my template, this tag would appear 3 times.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, how exactly do you want to identify the elements to be wrapped into the common parent in the output? Any group of elements starting with a `h` element? Any `h`, `i`, `j` elements or only any adjacent elements of that type? Also which XSLT processor/ XSLT version you use? If it is XSLT 2 or 3 see `group-starting-with` and `group-by` examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: `<A new group>` is not a valid tag.

Comment: @michael.hor257k my bad, I typed it as an example, indeed for xml the field is always in one word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="* except (h, i, j)"/>
        <ANewGroup>
            <xsl:copy-of select="h, i, j"/>
        </ANewGroup>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```